# How to build maven after importing an java spring project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

Hello i am new to java spring concepts . .so i downloaded a sample spring application and import that into eclipse ..i have read from spring tutorials either i have to install maven into eclipse to run spring projects ..

so i have installed maven and add a maven dependency *pom.xml* file into project but i got error in java build path as missing spring framework..can any one help me out from here ..

> Blockquote

Tell me how to add maven dependency for a imported java spring project

MY program file

```
package java4s;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class ClientLogic {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Resource res = new ClassPathResource("spconfig.xml");
        BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(res);

        Object o = factory.getBean("id1");
        WelcomeBean wb = (WelcomeBean)o;

        wb.show();

    }

}


<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
            "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
  <bean id="id1" class="java4s.WelcomeBean">

    <property name="message" value="Welcome to spring" />

  </bean>  
</beans>
```

This is my file pom.xml

```
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
> http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
> <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
> <groupId>Spring-Hello-World</groupId>  
> <artifactId>Spring-Hello-World</artifactId>  
> <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>   <dependencies>    <dependency>
>           <groupId>com.force.sdk</groupId>
>           <artifactId>force-springsecurity</artifactId>
>           <version>22.0.9-BETA</version>
>           <type>jar</type>
>           <scope>compile</scope>      </dependency>   </dependencies> </project> <dependency>
> 
> </dependency>
```

Further what kind of dependency i can add here..just now i have started working with springs

Comment: Hope it helps http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-convert-java-web-project-to-maven-project/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new too and for what I can say you can use your pom.xml to add all the dependencies that you need. 
For example, if you need to add spring context, you can just write its name and version. Maven thinks of how to find and import it.

The syntax of the example is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3-0</version>
</dependency>
```

For every dependence that you need, just write is groupId, artifactID and version, within the `dependency` tag and maven will think of everything.

Hence you will have a list of these dependency tags in the pom.xml.

Moreover, don't forget Maven use its structure ;)

Answer (score 1):

well,for solution of your problem you must have install maven properly in eclipse.

first of all convert your spring project to maven project

by

`Right click on project > Configure > Convert to Maven Project`

after that

right click on the project

click on maven

than click on update dependencies

```
 1)  Maven >Update Dependencies
```

and than after right click on project first

```
 2)  Run As > Maven Clean
```

and after maven clean do maven install

```
3)  Run As > Maven Install
```

at last clean and bulid your project.

hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in my opinion we have to do clarity on a few things. Spring is a modular application container that provides some functionality like DI, IoC, Security and Transactional Context. These functionalities help the developers to build different kind of application. Maven instead is a tool of project managment that allows to handle the the application life cycle, dependencies, reporting ecc. Then you are not obliged to use maven with spring, but  its use helps in many cases. Then first to add spring dependency in your pom you have to undestand what spring's module you need. For this reason you have to try  to understand what you are doing and update you question. Only after this step somebody can help you

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do not need Maven to run spring-java project. You can use maven but its not mandatory. 
For information on how to use maven visit:[Maven Tutorias](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/maven-tutorials/)