# mvn clean install errors with "Negative seek offset"

Tags: maven, ubuntu, neo4j, neo4j-spatial

mvn clean install causes build error
  here is the error what I am getting..

```
... 24 more
{[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.707s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 12 14:09:51 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/104M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-        plugin:2.1:unpack-dependencies (get-test-data) on project neo4j-spatial: Error unpacking   file: /home/dev237/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/spatial/osm-test-data/20100819/osm-test-data-20100819.jar to: /home/dev237/Projects /spatial/target
[ERROR] org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: Error while expanding /home/dev237/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/spatial/osm-test-data/20100819/osm-test-data-20100819.jar: Negative seek offset
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/
```

Comment: the message "Negative seek offset" indicates a corrupt download. Can you verify the files are there, readable and ok? In doubt you may also try to delete the lcoal maven repo and just try again?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178197/how-to-build-maven-after-importing-an-java-spring-project/24178362#24178362  
This answer may help you go through it

Comment: We changed file permission to 777.how can i delete maven repo..can you please specific about this.I am a beginer..

Comment: I used to change permission maven java version also..but I am getting same error..Please help me???

Answer (score 2):

Try renaming the repository folder "/home/dev237/.m2/repository" to make maven create a new repository and download all dependencies again.

Comment: I used to rename the repository folder and tried mvn clean install.But it gives many warnings and errors..Finally it gives Build error with following error message

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:unpack-dependencies (get-test-data) on project neo4j-spatial:

Comment: If you could add the content of your POM file to your question's body I may provide further help.

Comment: I am really sorry.It is big xml file.I tried to add it.but could not.It is very difficult  align xml file to stack overflows code style..it is too big..any other solution please???

Comment: Editing your question, copy & paste content of your POM, selecting and press STRG+K to make it a code section does not work?

Comment: Please edit your question with the new updates and don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. This is what I did to resolve it:

1. `cd` into `/home/dev237/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/spatial/osm-test-data/`
2. `rm -rf 20100819` (remove the problematic dependencies)
3. Re-run `mvn clean install`

At which point it built successfully.

This solution is arguably better than TekTimmy's as it avoids re-downloading all dependencies, regardless of if they're problematic or not. If they're all causing issues however, it may be easier to go with their solution.