# error in pom.xml while importing a maven project(jbehave selenium example project) in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, jbehave

I have to explore on jbehave with selenium. I downloaded the example from https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-tutorial. Then I imported the  jbehave-tutorial / etsy-selenium / java-spring folder as maven project in eclipse kepler. I have maven 3.0.4 version. But after importing the project as maven project, there are a lot of errors in pom.xml like:-

1) Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Could not find artifact org.jbehave:jbehave-maven-plugin:pom:3.10-
     SNAPSHOT
    - Missing artifact org.jbehave.site:jbehave-site-resources:zip:3.1.1

2) Missing artifact org.jbehave:jbehave-core:jar:3.10-SNAPSHOT

3) ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.jbehave.site:jbehave-site-resources:zip:3.1.1 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.jbehave.site:jbehave-site-resources:zip:3.1.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Access denied to: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jbehave/site/jbehave-site-resources/3.1.1/jbehave-site-resources-3.1.1.zip, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.

4) Missing artifact org.jbehave.web:jbehave-web-selenium:jar:3.6-SNAPSHOT

5)Missing artifact org.jbehave.web:jbehave-web-selenium:jar:3.6-SNAPSHOT

Comment: update your maven dependencies and than perform clean maven and install maven operation and than check ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178197/how-to-build-maven-after-importing-an-java-spring-project/24178362#24178362)this link may help you .

Comment: You won't get SNAPSHOT's from Maven Central. Why are you trying to get SNAPSHOT's of jbehave ?

Comment: how to update maven dependencies